# dart, websocket data types

Tags: websocket, dart

Are websockets like http requests in that we typically just pass json strings back and forth between client and server, or can they be configured to take custom binary objects, for example could I pass in a native dart object and have it automatically serialized on the client and pushed to the server where it could be deserialized into an object of the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets provide you no additional support with regard to serializing/deserializing.
The advantage over HTTP is that it provides full-duplex communications channel instead of the request/response flow of HTTP.

Comment: that's what I thought but it was just this that made me a bit confused https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/WebSocket.html#binaryType

Comment: you only can choose between BLOB or ArrayBuffer